# How to hide model Hard Disk in volume name ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu-mate, caja

How to hide model Hard Disk in volume name ubuntu mate

> [image: image Disk]

Comment: Looking in the Caja source code I see that it is hard-coded. If unsure, please ask the same question in the http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .